# ASP.NET MVC3 Stop executing action/controller in custom AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How I can stop executing action/controller without redirection, and only return Response with statusCode

```
public class MainAuthorizationFilter : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        ... [my Authorization login] ...

        if([Authorization fail])
        {
             if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
             {
                 filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                 // HERE I want stop executing action/controller because I want return only statusCode
             }
             else
             {
                  // In non-ajax request I just redirect me request and action/contoller isn't executed
                  filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult("Error", new RouteValueDictionary { { "errorCode", errorCode } });
             }
        }
    }

    base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

}

[MainAuthorizationFilter]
public ActionResult CreateFolder(...)
{
   CreateFolder(...);
}
```

Comment: 301 moved permanently doesn't really make sense here - 401 not authorized would make a lot more sense ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(401, "String description here if you want");
```

[`HttpStatusCodeResult` on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg401968(v=VS.98).aspx)

Note that the forms auth module may intercept this and convert it to a redirect to your login page - not sure if this applies to AJAX requests too, I haven't tried it...

Answer (score 2):

I would simply end the response like so:

```
public class MainAuthorizationFilter : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        ... [my Authorization login] ...

        if([Authorization fail])
        {
             if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
             {
                 filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;
                 filterContext.HttpContext.Response.End();

             }
             else
             {
                  // In non-ajax request I just redirect me request and action/contoller isn't executed
                  filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult("Error", new RouteValueDictionary { { "errorCode", errorCode } });
             }
        }
    }

    base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

}
```

Comment: Upvote because Response.End() prevents the redirection problems caused by forms auth like stated in the other answer.

Comment: @Nenotlep - Unfortunately it keeps executing the code in the Action that has authentication wrapped around it.

Comment: @Todilo - Unfortunately not.  The only way to make this work is implementing a custom module to make sure you get the response that you want.  While that isn't necessarily a bad thing, I didn't want to go through the effort for that.  So, I am returning an HTTP 418 (I've wanted to use it for awhile anyway) and letting my code handle that response as an unauthorized Ajax request.

Comment: @Ek0nomik I am using an actionfilterattribute but realised to abort the action the filterContext.Result need to be set. So I set it to 
                filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Redirect); which works like a charm.

Comment: @Todilo - Interesting... thanks for sharing.  I've got some other work I need to finish up, but, I'll put this on my list of things to try and let you know if it works out.  :)